# SQL Server Script Error: Database is Already in Use

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server deployment script running from visual studio that gives me the error:

> Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1828, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 The logical file name "myDB" is already in use. Choose a different name.

However, when I go into SSMS and try and drop this database, I get the error:

> Cannot drop the database 'myDB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Can anyone help me understand where this phantom filename is already stored so that I can delete it?

Thanks.

Comment: Some discussion about this error message: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vstsdb/thread/0826dd27-cec9-41ca-8f5f-779f4aadf916

Comment: @Marc B yes there are some good points there - I assumed that the intention really was to drop the database, but it might not be.

Comment: The intention is to rebuild it from a database project.

Comment: If it is another user attached to `myDB`, you can use the MSSMS activity monitor to see which connection/user is on that DB.

Comment: @MarcB - I stopped and then restarted SQL Server. Seems like that would've addressed another connection, no?

Comment: That's not always reliable. Connections can be initiated very quickly after startup depending on application configuration, I've also seen SQL Server Agent jobs sneak in and take my connection after I've set a database to single_user but before I've moved to my next action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second error message states that the database cannot be dropped because other sessions are currently connected to it. In order to kick all the users out, you can add this to your deployment script or run it manually before deploying. The `USE` command is to make sure there isn't a race condition when you are the one who's connected.

```
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE myDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DROP DATABASE myDB;
GO
```

Comment: `User does not have permission to alter database 'myDB', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.`

Comment: Is that from the deployment script or running manually in SSMS? What version is SQL Server (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)?

Comment: Run manually in SSMS. `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2573.0 (X64)   Feb  4 2011 11:27:06   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`

Comment: What does this yield? `SELECT user_access_desc, is_read_only, state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID('myDB');`? And are you sure you're running as a user with sufficient permissions to alter/drop/create databases?

Comment: I get zero rows in the result. Also, when I refresh the list of databases, this database no longer shows. I'm pretty sure I have unlimited permissions here.

Comment: So you get an error that you can't drop database myDB, but the database doesn't show in the list? Have you tried running your deployment script again? (You may have to comment out the line that says `DROP DATABASE myDB;` if it doesn't perform an `EXISTS` check). Now that you have seem to have successfully dropped the database, you may want to refresh Visual Studio so that it generates a `CREATE DATABASE` script and knows that the database doesn't already exist. I suspect you managed to drop the database somewhere in your attempts but are trying to troubleshoot the wrong problem.

Comment: Yes, I've gone back and forth many times. I quit and restarted both SSMS and Visual Studio. The main issue as I see it is that the name exists somewhere so that it thinks there is still a database with that name.

Comment: This shouldn't cause this conflict, though. Did you configure your database to have multiple files? Can you post the exact `CREATE DATABASE` command that Visual Studio is attempting to run? I suspect you have something like `CREATE DATABASE myDB ON (name='myDB', ...),(name='myDB', ...) LOG ON (...);`

Comment: Well, the script was created automatically and is very long. I've ran it many times before. I've messed something up somewhere.

Comment: Don't need to see the whole script, just the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

Comment: In fact, it was the `CREATE` command that was causing the error. I avoided digging into this because 1. A lot of it is Greek to me, 2. The script is generated automatically and has been working fine until now, and 3. it would've required a bit of editing not to publish names that would indicate the client's name. Now looking into why my script is getting corrupt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when trying to generate a database from a script. I was trying to do downgrade a SQL Server 2012 database to 2008 as per this article https://superuser.com/questions/468578/move-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-2008. However, when I ran the script initially, I got this error

```
The logical file name "emmagarland" is already in use. Choose a different name.
```

Turns out (after reading this article https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/106577/the-logical-file-name-database-is-already-in-use.html) in my restore script, I hadn't checked and changed the logical file names. I had to ensure the path is correct, and the change the **generated name for the log file**, else it tries to overwrite the .mdf file with the log and then throws this error. I fixed it by changing the name from xxxxx to xxxxxldf

```
 CREATE DATABASE [xxxxx] ON  PRIMARY 
 ( NAME = xxxxx', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
 Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\xxxxx.mdf' , SIZE =
 14400KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
 ( NAME = N'xxxxxldf', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
 Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\xxxxx_log.ldf' ,
 SIZE = 18560KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 GO
```

Sounds simple but I couldn't work out why this error was occuring when I was creating a brand new database!